# Windows Authentication box when Session Expires

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, active-directory

Im working on a project with Windows Authentication and Session States.

I have this code where i get the username, save it in a session and also in a label.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        var usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
        if (usr != null)
            Session["Application1_Data"] = usr.DisplayName;
            lbl_Login.Text = usr.DisplayName;
    }
}

After this I have the other pages where i receive the data of my session like this

if (Session["Application1_Data"] != null)
{
    lbl_Login.Text = Session["Application1_Data"].ToString();
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("Index.aspx");
}
```

If the session expires I made a redirect to the index page where I define the session but i want to remain on the same page,

How do I show a authentication box to enter windows credentials? instead of going back to the first page and starting afresh

Comment: Implement a base page, add your authentication logic inside `Init`, inherit all your pages from that base page view

Comment: But I will still get the same result inside INIT just that i would get it before the page load, or what am I missing?